# Magento 1.9 Display Track order info in user account

Tags: magento-1.9

i am new to **magento**. i want to display **track order info** in **users accoun**t.same as how **flipkart** is having.but here **delivery** of the **product** is done from the same shop itself.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not provide this feature by default, you need to used 3rd party extension for this feature.

I.e

https://www.apptha.com/magento/track-your-order

Comment: here the shop is not using any courier service.they themselves are delivering the product so for track order information i want to display information as displayed above only on basis of status's changed by admin.